# What types of files can 'Generic Text Only Printer's print?

Tags: linux, printing, text, printer

Today I added a printer on linux and tried to print an excel file. Clicked print but no reaction from printer. When I went to printer menu to troubleshoot I noticed that my printer's description was `Generic Text Only Printer`. What does this mean? Is my printer unable to print excel files in linux?

Comment: Basically, pure text files, like what you can type at the terminal prompt.

Answer (score 1):

The "Generic Text Only Printer" means that the printing subsystem (probably CUPS) either failed to get more specific model information or did not know how to control your printer in a more advanced way - perhaps because a necessary driver package was missing.

Please *edit your question* to specify the make and model of your printer, how did you connect it (wireless network? wired network? USB? something else?) and the name and version of your Linux distribution.